# Set Value Variavel Local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, variáveis, procedure

Gostaria atribuir o valor da variável local dentro do `SELECT`, como no exemplo abaixo, porém apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations."

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTE]
    @Param INT
AS
BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @VariavelLocal DECIMAL,@VariavelLocal2 DECIMAL   
    SELECT  (@VariavelLocal1 = SELECT COUNT(TesteId) FROM Table)
            ,(@VariavelLocal2 = 1)
            ,@VariavelLocal1 + @VariavelLocal2
            ,T2.T2Teste    
    FROM Table2 T2
END
```

Tem como fazer isto?

Answer (score 3):

A mensagem é clara. Basta não usar `SELECT` para atribuir valor **e** para retornar dados:

```
SELECT @VariavelLocal1 = SELECT COUNT(TesteId) FROM Table), 
       @VariavelLocal2 = 1

SELECT @VariavelLocal1 + @VariavelLocal2, T2.T2Teste
    FROM Table2 T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Para criar variáveis utilize [DECLARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188927.aspx) e para atribuir valores utilize [SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190356.aspx)

***Exemplo:***

```
DECLARE @VariavelLocal DECIMAL, @VariavelLocal2 DECIMAL,@VariavelLocal1 DECIMAL
SET @VariavelLocal1 = (SELECT COUNT(TesteId) FROM [Table]);
SET @VariavelLocal2 = 1;
SET @VariavelLocal = (@VariavelLocal1 + @VariavelLocal2);
```

***Pode-se fazer select após isso:***

```
SELECT @VariavelLocal, 
       @VariavelLocal1, 
       @VariavelLocal2
```

***No seu código:***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Teste
    @Param INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @VariavelLocal DECIMAL, @VariavelLocal2 DECIMAL,@VariavelLocal1 DECIMAL

    SET @VariavelLocal1 = (SELECT COUNT(TesteId) FROM [Table]);
    SET @VariavelLocal2 = 1;
    SET @VariavelLocal = (@VariavelLocal1 + @VariavelLocal2);

    SELECT @VariavelLocal, 
           @VariavelLocal1, 
           @VariavelLocal2
END
```

**Executar** *Sp_Teste*

```
EXEC Sp_Teste 1
```

*Referências:*

- [DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188927.aspx)
- [Instruções SET (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190356.aspx)